# How to convert all numeric values to floats when treated as string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
 label                                               data     start
37   1  Ses01M_impro04_F018 [145.2100-153.0500]: We're...  145.21000
38   2  Ses01M_impro04_M019 [148.3800-151.8400]: Well,...  148.38000
39   2                                     M: [BREATHING]  BREATHING
40   1  Ses01M_impro04_M020 [159.7700-161.8600]: I'm n...  159.77000
```

I parsed out the `start` column to get the starting timestamp for each row using this code:

```
df['start'] = df.data.str.split().str[1].str[1:-2].str.split('-').str[0]
```

I want to convert `df.start` into floats because they are treated as string right now. However, I can't simply to `.astype(float)` because of the actual string `BREATHING` in row 39.

I'd like to just drop the row containing alphabet characters (`row 39`). I do not know how to do this because at this point, all values in `df.start` are type `string`, so I can't filter with something like `isnumeric()`. How do I do this?

Comment: [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas-to-numeric) `df['start'] = pd.to_numeric(df['start'], errors='coerce')`. Could also wrap `df.data.str.split().str[1].str[1:-2].str.split('-').str[0]` with `to_numeric` to avoid 2 assignments.

Comment: Part 1 of the accepted answer goes through all of the options for how to use `to_numeric`.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting a skeletal code. You can modify and use it

```
if a.isnumeric():
  newa=to_numeric(a)
else:
  newa=a
```